# Wrong date inserted into SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to insert today's date in Database table. but problem is instead of today's date this value **"1900-01-01"** is inserted in the Database. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="msnDate" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="msnDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="msnDate">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Code-behind I wrote this code:

```
msnDate_CalendarExtender.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
```

This is the insert query

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-3T94FQ0;Initial Catalog=RAMS;Integrated Security=False;UID=sa;Password=sa123;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [tbl_musannet] ([pessenger_id],[mus_date]) VALUES('"+ ddlPessengerList.Text + "','" + msnDate.Text +"')", cs);
    cs.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cs.Close();
}
```

Comment: I don't  find any insert query here, show the query instead for the asp code

Comment: thank you.Insert query added.

Comment: Have you tried `msnDate_CalendarExtender.SelectedDate` instead for `msnDate.Text`; beware of Injection

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: No, I am not. Okay I am trying.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check what value you are getting for `msnDate.Text`

Answer (score 0):

You're using a string representation of a date without explicitly setting a format, which means it can vary according to the `Culture` settings of your ASP.NET application and according to the database server's settings too.

(e.g. is `05/06/11` the 5th of June 2011, or the 6th of May 2011, or the 11th of June 2005?)

You also have a problem with potential SQL injection too. You can fix both of these issues together by using parameters, which will pass the raw date-time value (and not a formatted representation) to the database server where there is zero ambiguity.

```
Int32 pessengerId;
if( !Int32.TryParse( ddlPessengerList.Text, out pessengerId ) ) {
    // abort, show error message
    return;
}

DateTime msnDate = msnDate.Value; // your `msnDate` control should have a strongly-typed way of getting the raw DateTime value, you should not attempt to parse a textual representation of a date/time.
if( msnDate < new DateTime( 2016, 01, 01 ) ) {
    // sanity-check the date range, if it's too far in the past or future reject it, according to your business rules
    return;
}

SqlCommand cmd = cs.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_musannet ( pessenger_id, mus_date ) VALUES( @passengerId, @musDate )";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pessenger_id", pessengerId );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@musDate ", msnDate);

cs.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cs.Close()
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I am trying this.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...